# Gutter Color не работает в Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Подскажите, почему плагин Gutter Color не работает, вернее работает не правильно?
Выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ImageMagick тоже установил, как требует сам плагин: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Gutter%20Color

Comment: Если мой ответ вам не поможет, укажите, какая у вас операционная система, куда установлен Gutter Color, покажите содержимое PATH и настройки `convert_path` у плагина.

Answer (score 2):

Прямоугольник, состоящий из красных и желтых полос, это изображение-заглушка в Sublime. Если вы видите такой прямоугольник, значит, с большой вероятностью, Gutter Color не может найти установленный ImageMagick для генерации образца цвета.

Дважды перепроверьте, верно ли вы задали значение для настройки `convert_path`, а также содержимое PATH, на предмет наличия пути к ImageMagick, после чего перезапустите Sublime. Если проблема останется, необходимо написать [разработчику плагина](https://github.com/ggordan/GutterColor/issues).

Answer (score 0):

В новых версиях ImageMagick нет файла "convert.exe"
можно переименовать magick.exe в convert.exe, и приписать в настройках sublime

{
  "convert_path" : "C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16/convert.exe"
}

Но все равно цвет не отображается, будут черные круги, 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

попробуйте другой плагин Color Highlighter

Comment: А зачем переименовывать, если можно изначально прописать путь к `magick`?

Comment: Без проблем, указание по умолчанию пути в настройках, ничего не меняет, потому что файла "convert.exe" там нет!

Comment: `convert_path` указывает на файл, которому вовсе необязательно называться `convert.exe`, разве нет?

Comment: Вообщем, Вы правы. Если цвет не менять через Ctrl+Shift+C то все отображается корректно. Но когда редактируется,то появляется такой цветной квадрат с полосками. Необходимо как то очистить кеш, чтобы новые цвета вступили в силу

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решается, во время инсталляции, необходимо выбрать опцию "Install legacy utilities" в программе ImageMagic

*Прописывать пути настроек и файлы нигде не нужно, все подхватывается автоматом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сбросить цвет попробуйте так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]